# linear independence on vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

In a vector space $\mathbb{V}$, my notes define linear dependence on a set of vectors $\left\{\left|x_1\right>, \left|x_2\right>, \left|x_3\right>, \left|x_4\right>..............\left|x_n\right>\right\}$, such that I could find at least one $\left|x_i\right>$ wherein the equation$$\forall \left|x_j\right>\in\mathbb{V},\forall\lambda_{j}\in\mathbb{C}\quad\sum_{j=1\\j\neq i}^{n}\lambda_j\left|x_j\right>=\left|x_i\right>\quad\lambda_{j}\neq0$$ holds true. Now, my question is, if I could find just one $\left|x_i\right>, i\in[1,n]\&i\in\mathbb{Z}$ then, shouldn't I also find the same for all other vectors, $\left|x_j\right>$ where $j\neq i$? Then why is the "at least one" clause put into the definition?

Comment: "$\forall \lambda_j \in \mathbb{C}\,$" That doesn't sound right. Recheck your notes and/or the course book.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry, I mean I have a complex vector space defined as say $\mathbb{V}\cap{\mathbb{C}}^k$. Then I would necessarily need to have, $\lambda_j\in\mathbb{C}$

Comment: The question was about the quantifier $\forall$. The way it's written, that equality can not hold for $\forall \lambda_j \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ unless *all* $n$ vectors are $0$. That's not the definition of a linearly dependent set.

Comment: @dxiv Well, that's what it says in the notes, (They are handwritten from class and I could have noted down wrongly) but if you prefer $$\forall \left|x_j\right>\in \mathbb{V}, \lambda_j\in \mathbb{C}$$ could you explain the difference. I would really learn something if you did. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\forall \left|x_j\right>\in\mathbb{V},\forall\lambda_{j}\in\mathbb{C}\quad\sum_{j=1\\j\neq i}^{n}\lambda_j\left|x_j\right>=\left|x_i\right>\quad\lambda_{j}\neq0$$

The condition as written, with $\forall\lambda_{j}\in\mathbb{C}$, implies that $\left|x_j\right> = 0$ for all $j=1, 2,\cdots,n$. This is because writing it for a set of $\lambda_j$, then for the correspondent set of $2\,\lambda_j$ it follows that $\left|x_i\right> = 0$. Then writing it for the initial set of $\lambda_j$ with all but one having the sign changed, and adding the two equalities, it follows that the corresponding vector $\left|x_j\right> = 0$.

For comparison, the condition modified as below gives a *sufficient* condition for the set of $\left|x_j\right>$ to be linearly dependent.

> $$\text{given}\; \left|x_j\right>\in\mathbb{V}, \;\exists i \;\;\text{for which} \;\;\exists \lambda_{j}\in\mathbb{C} \setminus{\{0\}}\;\;\text{so that}\;\;\sum_{j=1\\j\neq i}^{n}\lambda_j\left|x_j\right>=\left|x_i\right>$$

Written this way, the condition is symmetric in $i$ in the sense that if it holds for one of the $\left|x_i\right>$ then it will hold for any other $\left|x_j\right>$ by simply dividing by $\lambda_j \ne 0$ and rearranging the terms.

The condition, even modified as above, is however not *necessary* for linearly dependence in the [usual sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Definition). For example, any set of vectors containg the zero vector is linearly dependent, but does not necessarily satisfy the respective condition.